# Angular 5 deployment not finding json files on Windows Plesk server (GoDaddy)

Tags: json, angular

I just deployed my site from the dist file after compiling my Angular 5 code using the command ng build --prod.

Locally all the Json files are working perfectly, but after the build and on the server, I'm not getting any content from the JSON files. In the Chrome Tool I'm getting-

```
polyfills.a899d0f6ae…486a736.bundle.js:1 GET http://megakyle83.com/assets/json/contactMe.json 404 (Not Found)
main.cd1d757….bundle.js:1 ERROR 
e {headers: t, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://megakyle83.com/assets/json/contactMe.json", ok: false, …}
error
:
"<HTML>
↵<HEAD>
↵<TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE>
↵<BASE href="/error_docs/"><!--[if lte IE 6]></BASE><![endif]-->
↵</HEAD>
↵<BODY>
↵<H1>Not Found</H1>
↵The requested document was not found on this server.
↵<P>
↵<HR>
↵<ADDRESS>
↵Web Server at &#109;&#101;&#103;&#97;&#107;&#121;&#108;&#101;&#56;&#51;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;
↵</ADDRESS>
↵</BODY>
↵</HTML>
↵

headers
:
t {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message
:
"Http failure response for http://megakyle83.com/assets/json/contactMe.json: 404 Not Found"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
404
statusText
:
"Not Found"
url
:
"http://megakyle83.com/assets/json/contactMe.json"
__proto__
:
Object
```

I have my JSON files connected to my components using -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  contactMe: string;
  socialmedia: any;
  linkingPgs: object;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, public sanitizer: DomSanitizer ) {
    this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void
    {

      this.http.get<any>('./assets/json/contactMe.json').subscribe(
        data => {
          this.contactMe = data;
        })

      this.http.get<any>('./assets/json/socialMedia.json').subscribe(
        data => {
          this.socialmedia = data;
        })

      this.http.get<any>('./assets/json/headerInternalLinks.json').subscribe(
        data => {
          this.linkingPgs = data;
        })
    }
}
```

Is there something I did wrong with connecting the JSON files?

Answer (score 0):

In my apps I usually do not use the ./ in the beginning.

Example:

```
this.http.get<any>('assets/json/contactMe.json')
```

Comment: If you copy/paste the json url in the browser, does it request it correctly? Example: http://megakyle83.com/assets/json/contactMe.json (I tried this url and this is not working, the file does not exists).

Comment: Maybe the problem is not with the angular app itselt, but how you are serving it in your web server (via nginx or apache).

Comment: It isn't coming up at all if I put it in the browser. I'm using GoDaddy, I copied over the files from the dist folder after I ran ng build --prod